# How to send a http post request that contain '%%' in .net framework?

Tags: c#, http, post, encoding

I want to send a post request with c#.
the code that I write is:

```
string Pack = "Http://178.131.59.12:8081/rn/lo/?%%1111103643,A,130313073912,N3518.3952E04700.6455,10,85,0,FFFFFFFF,108\r\n";
Uri UR = new Uri(Pack);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.CreateDefault(UR);
req.Method = "POST";
WebResponse res = req.GetResponse();
Stream str = res.GetResponseStream();
int b = str.ReadByte() - 48;
if (b == 0)
    Console.WriteLine("Successful");
str.Close();
```

when Uri created, UR convert `%%` to irrelevent symbols like %25%◄ (because escaping)

I replaced % to %25 in Pack value

```
string Pack = "Http://178.131.59.12:8081/rn/lo/?%25%251111103643,A,130313073912,N3518.3952E04700.6455,10,85,0,FFFFFFFF,108\r\n";
```

but, the server does not accept http header.

when I send fist pack value to server with any browser, server accept it, but with programming NOT.

I think I should create a Uri without escaping UrsString.
How can I create a Uri with out escaping `UriString` in C#?

Comment: The query-string as shown ***is not valid***. What do you *want* it to do with an invalid url?

Answer (score 0):

Use HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp instead of HttpWebRequest.CreateDefault